# Integrating a composition

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm need to calculate this:

$$\int g'(x) (2g(x) - \frac{1}{g^2(x)}) dx $$

I think i have to integrate by parts, so i put:

$$ dv= g'(x) dx,v=g(x)$$
$$u=2g(x) - g(x)^{-2},du=2g'(x)-(g(x)^{-2})'$$

then i apply:
$$uv-\int vdu $$
and i should integrate:
$$\int g(x)( 2g'(x)-g'(x)^{-2} $$

I'm not sure this is the right way, i think there is an easier way but how?

Comment: Not integration by parts but substitution.

Answer (score 1):

> *I think there is an easier way but how?*

One may directly write
$$
\begin{align}
\int g'(x) \left(2g(x) - \frac{1}{g^2(x)}\right) dx&=2\int g'(x) g(x) dx- \int\frac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)} dx
\\\\&=g^2(x)+\frac1{g(x)}+C,
\end{align}
$$ where we have used that

> $$
> \left(g^{\alpha}\right)'=\alpha g' g^{\alpha-1},\quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R},
> $$

by virtue of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#One_dimension).